# create new cell array using two differently sized source arrays and matching the serial numbers

Tags: matlab, vector, pattern-matching, string-matching, cell-array

I have an array with a set of chronological serial numbers and another source array with random serial numbers associated with a numeric value. I wish to create a new cell array in MATLAB with the perfectly chronological serial numbers in one column and in the next I wish to insert the associated numeric value if the serial numbers match in both original source arrays. If they don't I simply want to copy the previous associated value until there is a new match.

For example

```
source input (serial)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

source input (random)
1    100
2    105 
4    106
7    107

desired output (data)
SR No           Value
1               100
2               105
3               105
4               106
5               106
6               106
7               107
```

Right now, the problem I have is that whenever I run the code below, I end up with empty cell values where there should be repeated values inserted by a (correctly working) program, i.e. in rows with serial numbers 3, 5-29, etc.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
j = 1;
A = {serial{1:end,1}};
B = cell2mat(A);
value = random(1,2);
data(:,1) = serial(:,1);

for k = 1:length(random)

    [row, col, vec] = find(B == random{k,1});
    tf = isempty(vec);

    if (tf ~= 1)
        value = random(row,2); 
        data(j,2) = random(row,2);
        j = j + 1;
    else
        data(j,2) = value;
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
```

How do I create this cell array without the empty values?

Note: Serial Values may be repeated in some cases - these are duplicates that cannot (or should not) be removed, but may need to be ignored by the program to avoid infinite loops.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide example inputs of the source arrays, and desired outptu.

Comment: I have included some examples. @OlegKomarov

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
serial = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
random = {1,100; 2, 105; 4, 106; 7, 107;};

data(:,1) = cell2mat(serial)';
data(:,2) = NaN;

for k=1:size(random,1)
    data(data(:,1)==random{k,1},2) = random{k,2};
end
for k=2:size(data,1)% what if there is no value for first serial number?
    if isnan(data(k,2))
        data(k,2) = data(k-1,2);
    end
end
disp(data)
```

BTW: I recommend you **not to use** MATLAB function name as a your variable name (i.e. random in your code).